# how to retrieve data from sqlite database and populate it in a listview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, android-listview

I have created 3 tables in sqlite database i.e.
Table 1) College (columns:- college_id, college_name, college_address, city, state, pincode, phone_number, rating, principal, email, website)
Table 2) Course (columns:- course_id, course_name, course_description, course_stream, duration, rating) &
Table 3) CollegeCourse (columns:- collegecourse_id, college_id, course_id, effsective_start_date, effective_end_date, effective_flag).

i am stuck on retrieving data from the SQLite database, displaying it in a listview, filtering the listview, and showing details when an item is clicked.

example:- http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7490/a58U0S.png

**Layout:**

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type college name to filter..." >

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.android.collegefinder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchcollegebtn);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        CollegeTable db = new CollegeTable(this);

        db.addCollege(new College(1, "Smt. Chandibai Himathmal Mansukhani College", "Opp. Railway Station, Smt.Chandibai Himathmal Mansukhani road", "Ulhasnagar", "Maharashtra", "421003", "02512734940", "B++", "Dr. Charanjit Kaur Singh", "principalchmc@gmail.com", "www.chm.edu"));
    db.getAllColleges();

    db.addCourse(new Course(1, "Economics", "N/A", "Arts", "3", 0));
    db.getAllCourses();

    db.addCollegeCourse(new CollegeCourse(1, 1, 1, "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000", "9999-01-01 00:00:00.000", 1));
    db.getAllCollegeCourse();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.searchcollegebtn) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchCollege.class));
    }
}
}
```

**DBHandler:-**

```
    package com.android.collegefinder;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class CollegeTable extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CollegeFinder";

public CollegeTable(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_COLLEGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE College ( " + 
    "college_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "college_name TEXT, " + "college_address TEXT, " + "city TEXT, " + "state TEXT, " + 
    "pincode TEXT, " + "phone_number TEXT, " + "college_rating TEXT, " + "principal TEXT, " + "email TEXT, " + "website TEXT )";

    String CREATE_COURSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Course ( " + 
    "course_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "course_name TEXT, " + "course_description TEXT, " + "course_stream TEXT, " + 
    "duration TEXT, " + "course_rating REAL )";

    String CREATE_COLLEGECOURSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE CollegeCourse ( " +
    "collegecourse_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "college_id INTEGER, " + "course_id INTEGER, " + "effective_start_date TEXT, " + "effective_end_date TEXT," + "effective_flag INTEGER )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_COLLEGE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_COURSE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_COLLEGECOURSE_TABLE);

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS College");

    this.onCreate(db);
}

private static final String TABLE_COLLEGE = "College";
private static final String KEY_COLLEGE_ID = "college_id";
private static final String KEY_COLLEGE_NAME = "college_name";
private static final String KEY_COLLEGE_ADDRESS = "college_address";
private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
private static final String KEY_PINCODE = "pincode";
private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_COLLEGE_RATING = "college_rating";
private static final String KEY_PRINCIPAL = "principal";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_WEBSITE = "website";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_COLLEGE_ID,KEY_COLLEGE_NAME,KEY_COLLEGE_ADDRESS,KEY_CITY,KEY_STATE,KEY_PINCODE,KEY_PHONE_NUMBER,KEY_COLLEGE_RATING,KEY_PRINCIPAL,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_WEBSITE};

public void addCollege(College college){
    Log.d("addCollege", college.toString());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_COLLEGE_ID, college.getCollegeId());
    values.put(KEY_COLLEGE_NAME, college.getCollegeName());
    values.put(KEY_COLLEGE_ADDRESS, college.getCollegeAddress());
    values.put(KEY_CITY, college.getCity());
    values.put(KEY_STATE, college.getState());
    values.put(KEY_PINCODE, college.getPincode());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, college.getPhoneNumber());
    values.put(KEY_COLLEGE_RATING, college.getCollegeRating());
    values.put(KEY_PRINCIPAL, college.getPrincipal());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, college.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_WEBSITE, college.getWebsite());

    db.insert(TABLE_COLLEGE, null, values);

    db.close();
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//COURSE TABLE  


private static final String TABLE_COURSE = "Course";
private static final String KEY_COURSE_ID = "course_id";
private static final String KEY_COURSE_NAME = "course_name";
private static final String KEY_COURSE_DESCRIPTION = "course_description";
private static final String KEY_COURSE_STREAM = "course_stream";
private static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
private static final String KEY_COURSE_RATING = "course_rating";

private static final String[] COLUMNS_COURSE = {KEY_COURSE_ID, KEY_COURSE_NAME, KEY_COURSE_DESCRIPTION, KEY_COURSE_STREAM, KEY_DURATION, KEY_COURSE_RATING};

public void addCourse(Course course){
    Log.d("addCourse", course.toString());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_COURSE_ID, course.getCourseId());
    values.put(KEY_COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
    values.put(KEY_COURSE_DESCRIPTION, course.getCourseDescription());
    values.put(KEY_COURSE_STREAM, course.getCourseStream());
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, course.getDuration());
    values.put(KEY_COURSE_RATING, course.getCourseRating());

    db.insert(TABLE_COURSE, null, values);

    db.close();

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// college course table

    private static final String TABLE_COLLEGECOURSE = "CollegeCourse";
    private static final String KEY_COLLEGECOURSE_ID = "collegecourse_id";
    private static final String KEY_COLLEGE_ID1 = "college_id";
    private static final String KEY_COURSE_ID1 = "course_id";
    private static final String KEY_EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = "effective_start_date";
    private static final String KEY_EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = "effective_end_date";
    private static final String KEY_EFFECTIVE_FLAG = "effective_flag";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS_COLLEGECOURSE = {KEY_COLLEGECOURSE_ID,KEY_COLLEGE_ID1,KEY_COURSE_ID1,KEY_EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,KEY_EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,KEY_EFFECTIVE_FLAG};

    public void addCollegeCourse(CollegeCourse collegecourse){

        Log.d("addCollegeCourse", collegecourse.toString());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_COLLEGECOURSE_ID, collegecourse.getCollegeCourseId());
        values.put(KEY_COLLEGE_ID1, collegecourse.getCollegeId());
        values.put(KEY_COURSE_ID1, collegecourse.getCourseId());
        values.put(KEY_EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, collegecourse.getEffectiveStartDate());
        values.put(KEY_EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, collegecourse.getEffectiveEndDate());
        values.put(KEY_EFFECTIVE_FLAG, collegecourse.getEffectiveFlag());

        db.insert(TABLE_COLLEGECOURSE, null, values);
        db.close();

    }
```

**SearchCollege.java:-**

```
    package com.android.collegefinder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SearchCollege extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchcollege);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something that isn't working?  What is your question?

Comment: Don't come here and post all your code without stating your problem. Do you really think someone is going to read and understand all that code just to help you? Be realistic. Help us to help you.

Comment: no. all are working properly @nasch. my question is:- how to retrieve data from sqlite database in a listview? i want to retrieve college_name column in a lisview. i just want coding of my above question. please help me i am new to android

Comment: @m0skit0 if you cant help me i have no problem. please dont interfare here let others help.

Comment: You didn't understand. I'm trying to help you. If you keep your question like this, nobody is going to help.

Comment: i have edited a question. please check. if you still dont understand anything. please let me know what you are not understanding. @m0skit0

Comment: So what part are you stuck on, retrieving data from the database, displaying it in a listview, filtering the listview, or showing details when an item is clicked?

Comment: exactly. thats what i am trying to say. @nasch  i am stuck on retrieving data from the database, displaying it in a listview, filtering the listview, and showing details when an item is clicked. please help me out. this is my first project and i want to show it in college.

Comment: if i understand your question you want to display your data in db in a listView ! if yes see this tut : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Then I would say your question is too broad.  Narrow it down to just one problem.  Solve that, then if you have another problem, ask another question.

Comment: i have shorten a question @nasch please check..

Comment: this example is different @y.feizi

Comment: please somebody help me

Comment: none can help you unless you minimize your question space. better do it yourself following the tutorial 

1.http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html
2.https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter
3.https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/

follow the tut, which suite you best

Comment: You didn't narrow your question at all.  You're still saying "i am stuck on retrieving data from the SQLite database, displaying it in a listview, filtering the listview, and showing details when an item is clicked."  That's four different questions. Pick ONE of those things to ask about, and show just the code relevant to that one thing.  Specify what exactly is giving you trouble, including the behavior you expect and the behavior you're actually getting.